# From PMML model to javascript model

Tags: javascript, r, pmml

I built a model in R and export it to PMML with "r2pmml" package, is there any way we can read this pmml file to a javascript object so that I can use it directly in the browser or in an extension? (I know that we have something like JPMML in java)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449075 and https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jpmml/piVCVVCN0hc/discussion